# How to Hash and Unhash a string from jaxb file?

Tags: java, hash, jaxb

I need to store an admin password in jaxb for users used to connect to an ldap server. I don't want to save the admin password in plain text in jaxb.
So i used a hash `Hash.asIsoString(Hash.sha256(enteredPass + KEY));`
how to Unhash the password used for connections:

```
<password>w4rDjsKhwqpfTHIUw4jCk8OTBsObwrsSwo/CmXDCmg/DgMKxw4vCtsODwrrDvT5OUCrCuQ==</password>
```

Comment: hashing is a _one way operation_.  you can't unhash a value.  if you need to get the original value back, you need to use some form of encryption, not hashing.  be aware, however, if this is running on the user's computer, then you are effectively giving out the admin password (if your users are reasonably tech savvy).  you should really be hiding this functionality behind a server somewhere if you want it to be truly secure.

Comment: There is no such thing as "unhashing". Hashing is not an encryption algorithm. It's not possible to get the original data back from a hash. How this normally works with passwords is that you compare the hash of whatever the user enters with the hash of the password that's stored somewhere. If the hashes are equal, then what the user entered was correct. No unhashing needed.

Comment: @jtahlborn This is an application sent for their customers and their network administrator setup the config file in the application. Then the users will connect with their Ldap credentials(Ldap authentication need admin password). So that's why i need to secure the admin credentials in config file.

Comment: is the config file residing on a server or on each user's computer?

Comment: it's on each users's computer

Comment: I think it was a bad idea to have the password in config file! the admin password used in admin connection to search a user by its uid in ldap server. But i changed the config file to have a set of base DN so the user bind directly without the admin connection . So no need to store the password in a config file . i was sure that's not a good idea to store an admin password . Thank you for your comments...